# SQL: Find the Hotels which are booked today

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a database, which consists of the following tables

```
HOTEL2(hno, hname, city, phone, room_type, price) 
GUEST2(gno, gname, address, phone) 
BOOKING2(Hno, gno, date_from, date_to)
```

I want to get all the information of today's booking.
I have written the following query but it's not working properly.

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM BOOKING
  3  WHERE DATE_FROM=(SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL);

no rows selected
```

I am using Oracle 10g.

Comment: `DATE_FROM=(SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL)` can be simplified to `DATE_FROM=SYSDATE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like below by using `trunc`

```
    SELECT b.*
    FROM BOOKING b
    WHERE DATE_FROM=trunc(sysdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  The logic is more like this:

```
select b.*
from booking
where date_from <= trunc(sysdate) and
      date_to >= trunc(sysdate);
```

Comment: Can you please explain it.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the datatype of the *"date_from"* and *"date_to"* is **date** then make the following sample sql fiddle works
   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2df0d/5
2. If the datatype is **varchar** then make sure to convert the sysdate to exact string format that has been stored in the table. The following a sample

   select TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD')
          ,TO_CHAR(sysdate,'MM-DD-YYYY')
   from dual